# Not compiling floor() ceil() with math.h include and -lm in gcc

Tags: math, gcc, include

I've been trying to compile my code and it doesn't want to work.

It gives me a message error that the reference is undefine.

I've used the math.h include in all my modules and my main file :

```
#include <math.h>
```

Here's the bash screen output :

```
bash-4.1$ make
gcc -W -Wall -lm -g   -c -o imagePGM.o imagePGM.c
gcc   tp2.o imagePGM.o   -o tp2
imagePGM.o: In function `imageContraste':
imagePGM.c:(.text+0x1067): undefined reference to `floor'
imagePGM.c:(.text+0x10c1): undefined reference to `ceil'
imagePGM.c:(.text+0x1103): undefined reference to `floor'
imagePGM.o: In function `imageRatio':
imagePGM.c:(.text+0x1371): undefined reference to `floor'
imagePGM.c:(.text+0x13aa): undefined reference to `ceil'
imagePGM.c:(.text+0x13ce): undefined reference to `floor'
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
make: *** [tp2] Erreur 1
bash-4.1$
```

I've used the "-lm" argument with the gcc.

Here's my makefile :

```
# Variables predefinies
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -W -Wall -lm -g

# Dependances
# Par defaut, make (sans arguments) ne se soucie que de la premiere dependance rencontree
# Aucune action par defaut ici, car gcc ne "sait" pas comment traiter ces dependances

# Dependances plus complexes : on ne peut melanger .c, .o et .h dans la meme dependance
tp2 : tp2.o imagePGM.o
tp2.o : tp2.c imagePGM.h

#    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c tp2.c
imagePGM.o : imagePGM.c imagePGM.h

clean :
    rm tp2 tp2.o imagePGM.o
```

Do i need to implement something else or do something specific ?

Comment: Your -lm is in the wrong place. It must come at the end.

Comment: You are passing `-lm` to the compiler. That has no effect. You must
pass it to the linker, which you are not, and in the linkage sequence it must appear after any object file that calls functions defined in `libm`. You need to get a basic understanding of compiling and linking with GCC and GNU Make. Here is [a fairly good beginner's tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html). For authoritative documentation, [here is the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) and [here is the GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've reworked my makefile from this :

```
# Variables predefinies
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -W -Wall -g
LIBS=-lm
# Dependances
# Par defaut, make (sans arguments) ne se soucie que de la premiere dependance rencontree
# Aucune action par defaut ici, car gcc ne "sait" pas comment traiter ces dependances

# Dependances plus complexes : on ne peut melanger .c, .o et .h dans la meme dependance
tp2 : tp2.o imagePGM.o
tp2.o : tp2.c imagePGM.h

#    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c tp2.c
imagePGM.o : imagePGM.c imagePGM.h

clean :
    rm tp2 tp2.o imagePGM.o
```

To this :

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -lm
DEPS = imagePGM.h
OBJ = imagePGM.o tp2.o 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -W -Wall -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

tp2: $(OBJ)
    gcc -W -Wall -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

The flags are linked at the end